# scala spray.json how to get Json Object

Tags: json, scala, spray

If I try Http Get Response `{"ReturnValue":""}`,
this Code make error.

> Caused by: spray.json.DeserializationException: Expected List as
>   JsArray, but got {"ReturnValue":""}

```
import spray.httpx.SprayJsonSupport._
import spray.json.DefaultJsonProtocol
import spray.http._
import spray.client.pipelining._
import scala.concurrent.duration._
import scala.concurrent.{ Await, Future }
import akka.actor.ActorSystem
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

class ApiHelper extends DefaultJsonProtocol {
  case class Robot(name: String, color: Option[String], amountOfArms: Int)

  implicit val RobotFormat = jsonFormat3(Robot)
  def CallAPI(httpMethod: String, subURL: String): String = {
    val apiLocation = "~~~"
    val timeout = 5.seconds

    implicit val system = ActorSystem("robotClient")
    return httpMethod match {
      case "GET" =>
        val pipeline: HttpRequest => Future[List[Robot]] = sendReceive ~> unmarshal[List[Robot]]
        val f: Future[List[Robot]] = pipeline(Get(s"$apiLocation"+subURL))
        val robots = Await.result(f, timeout)
        println(s"Got the list of robots: $robots")
        return "hello"
    }
  }
}
```

> Caused by: spray.json.DeserializationException: Expected List as JsArray, but got {"ReturnValue":""}  at
>
> spray.json.package$.deserializationError(package.scala:23)    at
>   spray.json.CollectionFormats$$anon$1.read(CollectionFormats.scala:29)
>     at
>   spray.json.CollectionFormats$$anon$1.read(CollectionFormats.scala:25)
>     at
>   spray.httpx.SprayJsonSupport$$anonfun$sprayJsonUnmarshaller$1.applyOrElse(SprayJsonSupport.scala:37)
>     at
>   spray.httpx.SprayJsonSupport$$anonfun$sprayJsonUnmarshaller$1.applyOrElse(SprayJsonSupport.scala:34)
>     at
>   scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction.apply(AbstractPartialFunction.scala:36)
>     at
>   spray.httpx.unmarshalling.Unmarshaller$$anon$1$$anonfun$unmarshal$1.apply(Unmarshaller.scala:29)
>     at
>   spray.httpx.unmarshalling.SimpleUnmarshaller.protect(SimpleUnmarshaller.scala:40)
>     at
>   spray.httpx.unmarshalling.Unmarshaller$$anon$1.unmarshal(Unmarshaller.scala:29)
>     at
>   spray.httpx.unmarshalling.SimpleUnmarshaller.apply(SimpleUnmarshaller.scala:29)
>     at
>   spray.httpx.unmarshalling.SimpleUnmarshaller.apply(SimpleUnmarshaller.scala:23)
>     at
>   spray.httpx.unmarshalling.UnmarshallerLifting$$anon$3.apply(UnmarshallerLifting.scala:35)
>     at
>   spray.httpx.unmarshalling.UnmarshallerLifting$$anon$3.apply(UnmarshallerLifting.scala:34)
>     at
>   spray.httpx.unmarshalling.UnmarshallerLifting$$anon$2.apply(UnmarshallerLifting.scala:30)
>     at
>   spray.httpx.unmarshalling.UnmarshallerLifting$$anon$2.apply(UnmarshallerLifting.scala:29)
>     at
>   spray.httpx.unmarshalling.package$PimpedHttpResponse.as(package.scala:51)
>     at
>   spray.httpx.ResponseTransformation$$anonfun$unmarshal$1.apply(ResponseTransformation.scala:33)
>     ... 13 more

Is there any way to get Json Object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can provide and use your own implementation of unmarshal which would construct JsValue instead of List[Robot]. JsValue would represent either valid response (list of robots) or arbitrary json response (or probably more custom object types).

```
  def unmarshal: HttpResponse ⇒ JsValue =
    response ⇒
      if (response.status.isSuccess)
        response.as[List[Robot]] match {
          case Right(value) ⇒ value.toJson
          case Left(error: MalformedContent) ⇒
            response.as[JsObject] match {
              case Right(value) ⇒ value.toJson
              case Left(error)  => throw new PipelineException(error.toString)
            }

      case Left(error) ⇒ throw new PipelineException(error.toString)
    }
  else throw new UnsuccessfulResponseException(response.status)
```

After the future (call to pipeline) returns JsValue you can try to convert it back again to List[Robot] in a controlled way (e.g. within a Try block) and in case of failure handle it as a custom json response.